# G-Suite API to purchase licenses for resellers

Tags: google-api, google-workspace, google-reseller-api, google-license-manager

I have made an extensive research on the reseller flow and found the following APIs

1. Reseller API - covers the flow for creating customers, assigning license to customers.

   - This document tells that '**A reseller buys user licenses from Google and resells these licenses to Google customers. A reseller can manage customer subscriptions directly, or, if customizing multiple services, a reseller can work with a service integrator to manage customers.**'
   - but it doesnot explain about how to have the licenses purchased from google before hand by the reseller using APIs

So, is it possible to have reseller / customer purchase licenses before hand using g-suite APIs ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Is your query resolved? What do you mean by before hand.